# Python TarFile with bz2 data

Tags: python, tarfile

Im trying to download a bz2 compressed tarfile and create a `tarfile.TarFile` object from it.

```
import MyModule

import StringIO
import tarfile

tardata = StringIO.StringIO()
tardata.write(MyModule.getBz2TarFileData())
tardata.seek(0)

tar = tarfile.open(fileobj = tardata, mode="r:bz2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/tarfile.py", line 896, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/tarfile.py", line 987, in bz2open
    pre, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/posixpath.py", line 92, in splitext
    i = p.rfind('.')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

According to the docs (http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) when you use `fileobj=` it is used in favor of file `name=`. Though, it looks like its still trying to access a null file?

> If fileobj is specified, it is used as an alternative to a file object
>   opened for name. It is supposed to be at position 0.

If I don't use `tarfile.open()` and I decompress the bz2 data and create the `tarfile.Tarfile` object manually it works with `StringIO` and `fileobj`:

```
>>> import MyModule
>>> import tarfile
>>> import StringIO
>>> import bz2
>>> tardata = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> tardata.write(bz2.decompress(MyModule.getBz2TarFileData()))
>>> tardata.seek(0)
>>> tar = tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=tardata, mode='r')
>>> tar.getmembers()
[<TarInfo 'FileNumber1' at -0x48e150f4>, <TarInfo 'FileNumber2' at -0x48e150d4>, <TarInfo 'FileNumber3' at -0x48e11fb4>]
>>>
```

I was trying to streamline since `tarfile` is supposed to support bz2 compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have thrown a look into `tarfile.py` on my systems. The line numbers were quite different (I have 2.6), so that I would suppose there was heavy work since 2.4.

Maybe the module had a bug in 2.4 times which has been corrected, or the said interface has changed thus the docs don't match your module version any longer.

It is just a guess, however.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly (after removing that MyModule stuff).